# Tkinter Button Binded to Keyboard Won't Count Class Parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, keyboard

I am trying to create the function 'count' that takes in an integer in the form of a variable, and adds 1 to it every time the return key is pressed, saving to the variable each time.

The argument needs to remain generic, because in the future this will run the same 'count' function on multiple variables depending on which button is pressed.

I've tried making `messi` a global variable by putting `global messi` at the top, but the same problem occurs.

```
import tkinter as tk

class PlayerStats:
    def __init__(self, name, touches):
        team = "Barcelona"
        self.name = name
        self.touches = touches
        
    def count(number):
        number = number + 1
        print(number)

messi = PlayerStats("Messi",0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event :PlayerStats.count(messi.touches))
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this snippet, it iterates it once, from 0 to 1, and then resets always printing out 1.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to fix would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving the result of the operation.

You're instanciating your `PlayerStats` class with a value of 0 for `touches`.
That value is then never mutated throughout your code.

When tkinter is calling your `count` method, it increments `number` but that variable never leaves the scope of the method, and is thus garbage collected.

To fix it, you should change your class to something like

```
import tkinter as tk

class PlayerStats:
    def __init__(self, name, touches):
        team = "Barcelona"
        self.name = name
        self.touches = touches
        
    def count(self):  # the first argument of a method is always a reference to the instance
        self.touches += 1
        print(self.touches)

messi = PlayerStats("Messi", 0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event: messi.count())  # You need to call the method on the instance you created.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dont edit python code as snippets , just format it as code by enclosing it with with triple backticks or ctrl + k or just copy and paste them.

Comment: thanks for your help, this worked in allowing me to iterate the variable and save it in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Dogeek. My functioning code from above now looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class PlayerStats:
    def __init__(self, name, touches):
        team = "Barcelona"
        self.name = name
        self.touches = touches
        
    def count(self, number):
        self.touches += 1
        print(number)

messi = PlayerStats("Messi",0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event :messi.count(messi.touches))
root.mainloop()
```

One thing this does not solve though is the ability to reuse that function for different variables. I am now trying to come up with an elegant way to do something like this:
import tkinter as tk

```
class PlayerStats:
    def __init__(self, name, touches, shots):
        team = "Barcelona"
        self.name = name
        self.touches = touches
        self.shots = shots

    def count(self, number):
        self.number += 1
        print(number)

messi = PlayerStats("Messi",0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Return>', lambda event :messi.count(messi.touches))
root.bind('<s>', lambda event :messi.count(messi.shots))
root.mainloop()
```

where number represents either messi.shots or messi.touches depending on what key is pressed. I'd like to do this without recreating a bunch of nearly identical functions for each key.